# Creating a function that calls a column both using a string and as a variable - use of base R and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, evaluation

I need some help understanding how evaluation works in the function I am writing:

The function would do two operations involving column "id", whose name is supplied by the user, among some other omitted things:

```
possible_matches <- function(i, df, id){
  
  k1 <- df$j[df$id == df$id[i]]
  df3 <-  df%>%
    mutate(index = {{id}})
  
  list(df3, k1)
}
```

As you can see, this would use two different ways of calling `id` - Is there an easy way to unify both approaches? At first, I've tried for the first part to write something in the line of `df[, 'id'] == df[i, 'id]`, but this would give an error saying that it is impossible to compare unequally sized data frames.

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1:5, 2:6),
                 j = 1:10)


possible_matches(2, df, V1)
```

Giving me:

```
[[1]]
   V1  j index
1   1  1     1
2   2  2     2
3   3  3     3
4   4  4     4
5   5  5     5
6   2  6     2
7   3  7     3
8   4  8     4
9   5  9     5
10  6 10     6

[[2]]
integer(0)
```

Which is clearly wrong since that is at least one row whose `V1` value is equal do `df$V1[2]`

Comment: please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is a unquoted column name

```
possible_matches <- function(i, df, id) {
     
     # // convert the id to string with `as_name` after converting to quosure
     idnew <- rlang::as_name(rlang::enquo(id))
     # // now we use [[ to subset the column and then specify the i index
     k1 <- df$j[df[[idnew]] == df[[idnew]][i]]
      df3 <-  df%>%
         mutate(index = {{id}}) # // curly-curly for quosure + evaluation (!!)

       list(df3, k1)
   }
```

-testing

```
possible_matches(2, df, V1)
#[[1]]
#   V1  j index
#1   1  1     1
#2   2  2     2
#3   3  3     3
#4   4  4     4
#5   5  5     5
#6   2  6     2
#7   3  7     3
#8   4  8     4
#9   5  9     5
#10  6 10     6

#[[2]]    
#[1] 2 6
```

---

If we want to use `filter`

```
possible_matches <- function(i, df, id) {            
        to_filter <- df%>% 
                      # // select the column
                      select({{id}}) %>% 
                      # // slice the row
                      slice(i) %>%
                      # // pull the column as vector
                      pull(1)
         k1 <- df %>% 
                   # // now we filter with the value from to_filter
                   filter({{id}} == to_filter) %>%
                   pull(j)
            df3 <-  df%>%
                mutate(index = {{id}})
       
              list(df3, k1)
         
         
       
      }
possible_matches(2, df, V1)
#[[1]]
#   V1  j index
#1   1  1     1
#2   2  2     2
#3   3  3     3
#4   4  4     4
#5   5  5     5
#6   2  6     2
#7   3  7     3
#8   4  8     4
#9   5  9     5
#10  6 10     6

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 6
```

Comment: is there a way to use in the second part some to the dplyr tools as in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html ? It is more intuitive to me

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito You meant creating the 'k1' part?

Comment: I guess you've edited your answer. But considering the edited answer, yes

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito earlier, i didn't notice that you wanted to change the `integer(0)` as i was thinking that it is the expected.  The issue was with indexing.  it should be outside the evaluation